# Embedding rational simple algebras in the real quaternions

Tags: nt.number-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Is there any way to embed a rational division algebra of dimension higher than 4 over its center in the real quaternions ?

I think not, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: See the following question; I think it is relevant.http://mathoverflow.net/questions/120777/skew-fields-inside-quaternion-division-algebras

Comment: Indeed, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.